# Need help on how to proceed with solving Laplace's Equation using Separation of Variables. Issue at $\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}) = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = \cos(\pi x) \sin(\pi y) \\ BCs: u = \cases{0 & (0,y) \\ 0 & (1,y) \\ 0 & (x,0) \\ 0 & (x,1)}$$

So we need to solve an inhomogeneous 2-D PDE with homogeneous BCs. First, we need to find the solution to Laplace's Equation i.e. the homogeneous equation. We can use several methods, but I think the most straightforward approach would be *method of separation of variables*. We start by assuming $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ and reorganizing our equation and then solving. So our Laplace's Equation would go from :
$$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$$
to:
$$\frac{\partial^2X}{\partial x^2}Y + \frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial y^2}X = 0 \\ \text{or we can write it as: } X''Y + Y''X = 0$$.
And then we simply reorganize and isolate variables:
$$X''Y = -Y''X \\ \frac{X''}{X} = -\frac{Y''}{Y} = \lambda \\ \text{(1).}\frac{X''}{X} = \lambda,\text{(2).}-\frac{Y''}{Y} = \lambda$$

And we write these in their characteristic form to obtain: $$r^2-\lambda = 0, r^2+\lambda = 0 \\ r = \pm \sqrt{\lambda}, \pm i\sqrt{\lambda}$$ giving us:
$$\text{(3). } X(x) = C_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + C_2\sin(-\sqrt{\lambda}x) BCs\cases{X(0) = 0 \\ X(1) = 0}\\ \text{(4). } Y(y) = c_3e^{\lambda y} + c_4e^{-\lambda y} BCs\cases{Y(0) = 0 \\ Y(1) = 1}$$

I started on the case for $\lambda > 0$, and I got stuck on solving for Y. I'll work out what I have below up to where I got stuck.

Starting with (3):

$$X(0) = 0 = C_1 \\ X(1) = 0 = C_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}) \\ \text{and we want a non-trivial solution, so } C_2 \ne 0 \text{ and we'll instead define the eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenfunction}$$  $$\sin^{-1}\sin(n\pi) = \sin^{-1}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}) = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_n = n^2\pi^2\\ \text{ and we arrive at our corresponding eigenfunction: } X_n = \sin(n\pi)$$
(We dropped off the constant $C_2$ because we were writing out the eigenfunction, so we weren't concerned with it) I'm assuming the full form which I would work with later would be:

$$\text{(5). } X(x) = C_2\sin(n\pi)$$

Now we need to find $Y(y)$ which is where I got stuck (albeit I might have made mistakes above). Starting with (4) and applying BCs, we get:
$$Y(0) = 0 = c_3 + c_4 \rightarrow c_3 = -c_4 \\ Y(1) = 0 = c_3(e^{\sqrt{\lambda}} - e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}) \\ \text{and again, we want non-trivial solutions, so we assume }c_3 \ne 0 \\ e^{\sqrt{\lambda}} - e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}} = 0 \rightarrow \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}) = 0$$

So, just like with (3), we are tasked with finding the eigenvalue, $\lambda$:
$$\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(n*0)) = \sinh^{-1}(\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda})) \\ n^2*0 = \lambda \\ \text{(6). } Y_n = \sinh(0n^2)$$

Here lies the problem. There is only 1 value of $\lambda$ that yields $\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}) = 0$. Unless there was another way to obtain 0 for this function? I know you can use complex analysis to get say $\sin(\theta) = 2$ and such, but I have very little experience in actual complex analysis aside from very basic bits of knowledge, but perhaps that's what I do next.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: The boundary conditions must be satisfied by the solution to the *inhomogeneous* PDE (also known as Poisson's equation), not by the solution to the homogeneous PDE.

Comment: @Gonçalo Apologies for the delayed response. You're right! I did in fact use the original BCs for the general solution, this would be incorrect. On my previous 1-D case that you had helped me with, I had inhomogenous BCs and an inhomogeneous PDE, the solution was the general solution using inhomogeneous BCs + the particular solution using homogeneous BCs. If I have Homogeneous BCs and an inhomogeneous PDE, I guess I would just skip the step for finding the general solution, right?

Comment: What I wrote in that occasion also applies here. If you tried to solve the present problem using Green's function, the solution would be given by $u(x,y)=u_0(x,y)+\int G(x,y;x',y')\cos(\pi x')\sin(\pi y')dx'dy'$, where $u_0$ is the solution to the homogeneous PDE satisfying the given BCs, and $G$ is the Green's function of the Laplacian operator satisfying homogeneous BCs. In the present case, however, $u_0=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way of solving your PDE. First, notice that when we apply the Laplacian operator $\Delta:=\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$ to $\sin(\pi y)$, the result is a multiple of $\sin(\pi y)$: $\Delta \sin(\pi y)=-\pi^2\sin(\pi y)$. Second, $\sin(\pi y)$ vanishes at $y=0$ and at $y=1$, which are two of the boundary conditions of the problem. These observations suggest that the solution to the PDE
$$
\Delta u(x,y)=\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) \tag{1}
$$
has the form $u(x,y)=f(x)\sin(\pi y)$. Plugging this ansatz into $(1)$, we obtain an ODE for $f(x)$:
$$
(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2)f(x)\sin(\pi y)
=[f''(x)-\pi^2f(x)]\sin(\pi y) 
=\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) 
$$
$$
\implies f''(x)-\pi^2f(x)=\cos(\pi x). \tag{2}
$$
It's straightforward to solve $(2)$; the result is (check!)
$$
f(x)=A\cosh(\pi x)+B\sinh(\pi x)-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(\pi x). \tag{3}
$$
The boundary conditions $u(0,y)=u(1,y)=0$ imply $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Applying these conditions to $(3)$ and solving for $A$ and $B$, we obtain
$$
A=\frac{1}{2\pi^2},\qquad B=-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{1+\cosh(\pi)}{\sinh (\pi)}\right). \tag{4}
$$
Finally, collecting all pieces together, we can write the solution to $(1)$ as
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left[\cosh(\pi x)-\cos(\pi x)-
\left(\frac{1+\cosh(\pi)}{\sinh (\pi)}\right)\sinh(\pi x)\right]\sin(\pi y). \tag{5}
$$

Comment: I should have included in my problem that I had chosen a solution to arrive at already. The solution I had chosen was $u(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$. This solution yields the forcing term and satisfies the given homogeneous BCs. I crunched the numbers on what you have found and it does indeed solve the PDE and satisfy the BCs. Allow me to parse through your steps for a bit.

Comment: This does all end up working out. As I'm finding out, I'm not very good with solving inhomogeneous differential equations, allow me some time tomorrow to verify (2). Was it the characteristic/complementary equation used for the homogeneous part and guessing the form of the particular part (where "guessing the form" is *undetermined coefficients* if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: Yes, that's how I solved Eq. (2).

Comment: Forgot to mention, but I dropped a solution verifying the work. It all works out. It looks like you assumed $u(x,y)$ was a product of a function of x and a function of y, and then rather than use method of separation of variables, you took advantage of the trig forcing terms and guessed that one of the solutions was $Y(y) = sin(\pi y)$ and used this to set up an ODE. This was a very clever approach. I'll keep it in mind if I see something similar in the future. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So just to verify everything, we can use *method of separation of variables* to say $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ and from there, rather than go through the typical method we make another assumption that $Y(y) = \sin(\pi y)$ and go from there. Why we do this? I assume it is an offshoot of the method of undetermined coefficients but for 2-D cases where we can make a guess for a part of the solution for an inhomogeneous problem when the forcing term is a trigonometric function.

This provides $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = X(x)\sin(\pi y) \rightarrow X''\sin(\pi y) -X(x)\pi^2\sin(\pi x)= \cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) \\ \sin(\pi y)(X''-\pi^2 X)=\cos(\pi x) \sin(\pi y) \\ X''-\pi^2X = \cos(\pi x); X(0) = 0, X(1) = 0$$
And then we need to solve the ODE:

1. start with homogeneous equation: $X''-\pi^2X = 0$

$$r^2-\pi^2 = 0 \rightarrow r = \pm \pi \\ 
\text{general solution: }X_g = c_1e^{-\pi x}+c_2e^{\pi x} \\ 
\text{and } \cosh(a) - \sinh(b)= e^{-\pi x},\cosh(a)+\sinh(b) = e^{\pi x} \\ 
X_g = c_1(\cosh(\pi x)-\sinh(\pi x))+c_2(\cosh(\pi x)+\sinh(\pi x)) \rightarrow(c_1+c_2) = A,B=(c_2-c_1) \\ \boxed{X_g = A\cosh(\pi x) + B\sinh(\pi x)}\\$$

2. use method of undetermined coefficients : guess particular solution

$$\text{solution to inhomogeneous problems of the form } a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y = f(x) \text{ often takes the form } c_1e^{-\sqrt{r}x} + c_2e^{\sqrt{r}x} \text{ or } A\sin(\sqrt{r}x)+B\cos(\sqrt{r}x) \text{ and we pick one of these and determine the coefficients}\\ X_p = C\cos(\pi x) + D\sin(\pi x)\\
X(x) = X_g + X_p = A\cosh(\pi x) + B\sinh(\pi x) + C\cos(\pi x) + D\sin(\pi x)$$

3. plug into inhomogeneous differential equation

$$X''-\pi^2 X = \cos(\pi x) \\ 
(X_g+X_p)''-\pi^2(X+X_p) = \cos(\pi x) \rightarrow X_p''-\pi^2X_p =\cos(\pi x) \\ -\pi^2(C\cos(\pi x)+D\sin(\pi x))-\pi^2(C\cos(\pi x)+D\sin(\pi x))=\cos(\pi x) \\ -\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \cos(\pi x) = C \cos(\pi x) + D\sin(\pi x) \\ 
\text{the simplest coefficients that solve this are }D=0, C = -\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \\ X = A\cosh(\pi x) + B\sinh(\pi x) -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(\pi x) $$

4. Solve for homogeneous coefficients

$$X(0) = 0 = A - \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \rightarrow A = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \\ 
X(1) = 0 = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cosh(\pi) + B\sinh(\pi) + \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \\ -B\sinh(\pi x) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}(\cosh(\pi)+1) \\
 B = -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\frac{1+\cosh(\pi)}{\sinh(\pi)} \\ 
u(x,y) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cosh(\pi x) - \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\frac{1+\cosh(\pi)}{\sinh(\pi)}\sinh(\pi x) - \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(\pi x)\bigg)\sin(\pi y) \\ \boxed{u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\bigg(\cosh(\pi x) -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\frac{1+\cosh(\pi)}{\sinh(\pi)}\sinh(\pi x) - \cos(\pi x)\bigg)\sin(\pi y)}$$